# Error in creating a function with a trait-bounded parameter wrapped in Option enum

Tags: rust, enums, traits

I want to create a method for my `MyError` enum (whose variants are the different error types in my program) that returns a `String` value that describes the given `MyError` variant. For example:

```rust
pub enum MyError {
    Error1,
    Error2,
}

impl MyError {
    pub fn to_str(&self) -> String {
        match self {
            Error1 => format!("Error1: bla bla bla"),
            Error2 => format!("Error2: na na na"),
        }
    }
}
```

This is all well and good, but the problem is, I have a new error variant (say `Error3`) that must pass a parameter to its `format!()` macro in the method, like this:

```rust
Error3 => format!("la la la {:?}", arg),
```

This parameter can be of any type as long as it can derive the `Debug` trait. So my solution was

```rust
pub enum MyError {
    Error1,
    Error2,
    Error3
}

impl MyError {
    pub fn to_str(&self, arg: Option<&impl fmt::Debug>) -> String {
        match self {
            Error1 => format!("bla bla bla"),
            Error2 => format!("na na na"),
            Error3 => format!("la la la {:?}", arg),
        }
    }
}
```

Where I wrap the trait-bounded parameter in `Option` since some variants of `MyError` do not need it (e.g. `Error1`). This works for the `Error3` variant, I can do the following without any compilation error:

```rust
eprintln!("{}", MyError::Error3.to_str(Some(vec![1, 2, 3])));
```

It prints the associated error message of `Error3`. But when I try to use the method to the other variants which require no additional parameter, e.g. calling

```rust
eprintln!("{}", MyError::Error1.to_str(None));
```

It returns the following compilation error:

```
type annotations needed

cannot infer type for type parameter `impl fmt::Debug` declared on the associated function `to_str`rustc(E0282)
```

Why can't the compiler infer the type of `None` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it can't infer this is likely due to some annoying edge cases. The main one being determining the size of the enum being passed. The size of an enum type depends on the size of its largest variant. You can see this with `assert_neq(std::mem::size_of::<Option<i32>>(), std::mem::size_of::<Option<i8>>());`. Without knowing what concrete type it contains, we can't know how much space the function should use when passing the argument.

The easiest way is probably to allow the user to specify a concrete type as a type parameter. Even if you pass in `None`, you can still specify a concrete type as an alternative (Ex: `error.to_str::<()>(None)`).

```rust
impl MyError {
    pub fn to_str<D: fmt::Debug>(&self, arg: Option<&D>) -> String {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Otherwise, I would suggest detaching the methods to simply avoid the issue entirely.

```rust
impl MyError {
    pub fn to_str(&self) -> String {
        match self {
            Error1 => format!("bla bla bla"),
            Error2 => format!("na na na"),
            Error3 => format!("la la la"),
        }
    }

    pub fn to_str_with_context(&self, arg: &impl fmt::Debug) -> String {
        match self {
            Error1 => format!("bla bla bla"),
            Error2 => format!("na na na"),
            Error3 => format!("la la la {:?}", arg),
        }
    }
}
```

Beyond that, I can only offer general coding tips.
My first instinct is that you may find it more convenient to have a display wrapper.

```rust
pub struct MyErrorWithContext<'a, D> {
    err: &'a MyError,
    context: Option<&'a D>,
}

impl<'a, D: fmt::Debug> fmt::Display for MyErrorWithContext<'a, D> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        match self.err {
            Error1 => write!(f, "bla bla bla"),
            Error2 => write!(f, "na na na"),
            Error3 => write!(f, "la la la {:?}", &self.context),
        }
    }
}

impl MyError {
    pub fn display<D: Debug>(&self, context: Option<&D>) -> MyErrorWithContext<D> {
        MyErrorWithContext {
            err: self,
            context,
        }
    }
}


println!("Error: {}", error.display(Some(&foo)));
```

Comment: All your suggestions are nice, but I would use the first for its simplicity. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the concrete type, even for `None`. Like this:

```
let n: Option<&Vec<usize>> = None;
eprintln!("{}", MyError::Error1.to_str(n));
```

Even though the function (method) only specifies a trait bound, not a concrete type, the *compiler* needs to know *exactly* the type of each value a caller passes to that function.

And of course, you can call the function with values of different type (but each of those needs to be clear and must adhere to the trait bound). An example:

```
pub fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let v2 = "A str here";
    eprintln!("{}", MyError::Error3.to_str(Some(&v1)));
    eprintln!("{}", MyError::Error3.to_str(Some(&v2)));
    let n: Option<&Vec<usize>> = None;
    eprintln!("{}", MyError::Error1.to_str(n));
    let n2: Option<&Vec<String>> = None;
    eprintln!("{}", MyError::Error1.to_str(n2));
}
```

You can learn more [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/impl-trait.html).